# Why my static HTML file not serving in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I don't know why my static html files are not serving in express.js when I click on about it not serving about.html but instead only plain text about which i written in res.end('about')
don't know what is the issue.[image]

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
const path = require('path');

const static_path = path.join(__dirname,"../public");
app.use(express.static  (static_path));
console.log(static_path)

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   res.send('index')
})

app.get("/about", (req,res)=>{
   res.send("about")
});

app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
   res.status(404).send("404 page is not found")
})

app.listen(port,  ()=>{
   console.log(`this website is running on ${port}`)
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `/about` wont magically match `/about.html`

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone thanks for the comment, I have tried all this little logics already not working my question is what is the meaning then declaring of "const static_path = path.join(__dirname,"../public");
app.use(express.static  (static_path));"  if i have to put full path every time in res.send() becuase my index file is serving without any problem why this not happening with that too any idea ???

Comment: Dont just post a picture of your code. `res.send` sends plain text and no file. use `res.sendFile`. Either dont use route handling for `/about` to serve `about.html` (or any other route/static file) or use `res.sendFile` in each route handler. I suggest to read more on the docs how route handling works. Squiba has some good points in his comments/answer.

Comment: its how express works, you define the routes and it serves it, express.static will serve static files as-is, it does not rewrite `.html` off the end files, index.html works as the defacto index so it wont need the .html at the end. Ideally, you should use a templating system like ejs then use res.render, else you might as well use a static webserver

Comment: thanks for the explanations. I got your points

Answer (score 0):

use res.sendFile() instead of res.send()

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment I have tried that too but not luck still the same output i don't know what wrong in the code..

Comment: you are not putting any effort. don't just write "about" write the full path of the file, do something like res.sendFile('../public/about.html', { root: __dirname })

Comment: then whats the meaning of this "const static_path = path.join(__dirname,"../public");
app.use(express.static  (static_path));" if I have to write the full path in directly every time.

Comment: @KuldeepSingh You are setting up a route handler for the url. Remove every route handler and use only the static file handler or use squiba solution with `res.sendFile`. 
You are overriding the static file handler. The Downvote is not deserved!